# Newbie to xpath

Tags: xpath, onclick

I would like to know how create xpath for the following , where I need to click the guy Test2 which in turn opens a new window.

```
<div class="example">
<a href="#" onclick="parent.navigateFrame('../test/test.aspx', 'Test2'); return false;" target="_self">
<h1>Test2</h1>
</a>
<p></p>
</div>
```

I am new to all this, so its taking a while to figure out how to form the xpath. 
I tried the following ways with no success.

**(1)** `xpath(//*[contains(@class, 'example' and @onclick, 'Test2')]`

**(2)** `xpath(//*[contains(@class, 'example' and @onclick, 'parent.navigateFrame('../test/test.aspx', 'Test2')')])`

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
//div[@class='example']/a
```

has two steps (separated by `/`). The first one will select the `div` which has a `class` attribute containing the text `example`. The last one (which is the element you want), will select all the `a` elements in that `div`.

To get the *first* `a` element, you can add a predicate:

```
//div[@class='example']/a[1]
```

That's a positional predicate. From what you've tried, you require that your predicate check other things, such as a value in the `onclick` attribute. In this case, you should use:

```
//div[@class='example']/a[contains(@onclick, 'Test2')]
```

As you can see, the first predicate was used to restrict the `div`. An expression such as `//div` selects *all* `div`s in your file. Predicates restrict that. `[@class='example']` reduces that set to the set of `div`s that have a class attribute containing exactly `'example'`.

But you don't want a `div`. You need an `a` to click. So now you proceed with one more step. Unless you prefix your path with something like `parent::` or `following::` you are using the `child::` axis, which is *default*. That means that *each* step moves down the tree to the child nodes. Since `a` is a child of `div`, you can use `div/a` (which is the same as `child::div/child::a`). Again it selects *all* `a` elements in that *context*, so you need to restrict again, with one or more predicates for the `a` element.

*If* there may be other classes besides `example` in your `div`, you can use `contains()` (ex: `<div class="some-class example some-other-class">`, but be aware that it might match more than you expect (`example-1`, `my-example` will also match `contains(@class, 'example')`.

Comment: Woah thank you, that was pretty quick. And the answer was pretty descriptive.
 But I have no luck. Is it got to do something with the 'parent.navigateFrame' syntax, that doesn't point to the 'Test2' guy?

Comment: If you need to extract the JavaScript from the `onclick` attribute you can use `//div[@class='example']/a[contains(@onclick, 'Test2')]/@onclick`

Comment: And this will give you the `../test/test.aspx`: `substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='example']/a[contains(@onclick, 'Test2')]/@onclick, "parent.navigateFrame('"), "', 'Test2'")`

Comment: All those expressions work with the text you pasted above. Reasons for it to fail may include a default namespace declaration in some ancestor node (`xmlns="..."`), or that the code you posted is not the same as the actual one, or that the actual file is dynamic and has changed,

Comment: Thanks.. that link was in an iframe itself and somehow wasn't working, but my coleague showed me an alternative way to go to that link. Why it isnt working is another day of work to look at . Thanks anyway! Learnt something new anyway!